# Rhapsody java api

Tags: java, rhapsody

I'm trying to use Java api of Rhapsody. When I looked at the tutorial of the api, there is lots of different irp interfaces, also sometimes they have the same operations.. I could'nt make concrete. For example, I'm trying to reach interface package.
I wrote the following code segment.

```
IRPApplication rpy=null;
IRPModelElement ele =null;
rpy= RhapsodyAppServer.getActiveRhapsodyApplication();
```

How can I reach the interfaces in Interface package and the operations in one interface class?

Answer (score 1):

This should help (there's a sample project at the end of the article)

[Rhapsody Helpers](http://merlinscave.info/Merlins_Cave/Tutorials/Entries/2012/3/1_Helpers__Plugins_or_Standalone.html)

Comment: Answers only pointing to a link are generally unhelpful. Could you copy a relevant section of code so the answer stays on this site, just in case your link were to go down?

Answer (score 0):

```
IRPProject project = rpy.activeProject();
IRPModelElement thatInterface = project.findNestedElementRecursive("[interface name]", "Interface");
```

if the interface is at the top level, you don't need Recursive, but it's not a bad idea to leave it in either way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can find a package that contains the interface

```
IRPModelElement interfacePackage = project.findNestedElement("[package name]", "Package");
```

This is how you can find the interface in that package

```
IRPClass m_interface = (IRPClass)interfacePackage.findNestedElement(interfaceName, "Interface");
```